# Expected value mixed poisson process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, poisson-process

I have a geometric counting process defined as a mixture between the family of homogeneous Poisson process with respect to the random intensity $\Lambda$ which is exponentially distributed with parameter $\mu=2$. I have some issues with the request to find the $E[N(1)|N(2)=1]$. I tried with the fact that $E[N(t)]=E[\Lambda]t$ but I'm stuck because I don't know how to manage the condition $N(2)=1$.
Could be that $N(1)|N(2)=1 $ is $Bin(1,1/2)$ and for this reason the $E[Bin(1,1/2)]= 1/2 $ Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Hint: Compute, for every positive $\lambda$, $$E(N(1)\mid N(2)=1,\Lambda=\lambda)$$

Comment: I tried with this: $E[N(s)|N(t)=n]=\sum_{k=0}^n k*P[N(s)=k|N(t)=n]$ and this led me to the fact that was binomial distributed but I don't know if I'm correct

Comment: @Loulou I don't think what you write down here "leads" to the binomial distribution... But yes, it is true that conditional on $\Lambda = \lambda$ and $N(2) = n,$ $N(1)$ is Bin(n,1/2) (Now, actually show this.) And therefore $$E(N(1)\mid N(2)=1,\Lambda = \lambda)= \frac{1}{2}.$$ So what can you conclude about $E(N(1)\mid N(2)=1)$?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen if it was binomial for the condition $\Lambda = \lambda$ now  I have to make $\int \frac{1}{2} f_\Lambda(\lambda)$ ?

Comment: @Loulou Sure, and what is that?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen $E[N(1)|N(2)=1]=\int \frac{1}{2} f_\Lambda(\lambda) d\lambda$ correct? So I finished

Comment: @Loulou Well, you need to do the integral. (Or see what the integral must come out to by definition.)